# C# new() allocation returning null or "0"

Tags: c#, memory, allocation

I have a static variable declared in another class. That class declares it:

```
public class BaseClass : MonoBehaviour
{ 
   // Static so should only allocate once
   public static SubClass m_subObj  = new SubClass();
}
```

I've tried bracing the allocation in a "lock(object)" but m_subObj is always null. I've included some code that shows the unlocked version.

Here is the code that bares down on it:

```
public class BaseClass : MonoBehaviour
{ 
   // Static so should only allocate once
   public static SubClass m_subObj  = new SubClass();  
}

public class SubClass : BaseClass 
{

   void Start() 
   {
       if (m_subObj)
       {
         Debug.Log("SubClass:Start 1 - SubClass allocated");
         return;
       }

      // This will pass
      if (!m_subObj)
      {
         Debug.Log("SubClass:Start() 2 - Huh? Should be allocated");
         m_subObj = new SubClass();
      }

      // This will pass too
      if (!m_subObj)
      {
       Debug.Log("SubClass:Start() 3 - DOUBLE Huh? Should be allocated");
      }
}
```

I expected:

> (Run it)
>   SubClass:Start 1 - static SubClass allocated

But got:

> (Run it)
>   SubClass:Start() 2 - Huh? Should be allocated
>   ? SubClass:Start() 3 - DOUBLE Huh? Should be allocated

Comment: you can't compare references like `!m_subObj` in c#.

Comment: @DanielA.White The `MonoBehaviour` class has an [implicit cast to `bool`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html). Not sure I understand when it's supposed to produce true or false, though.

Comment: @JLRishe ugh thats nasty.

Comment: Aha, an implicit conversion to `bool` would indeed allow the code to compile. It [looks like](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html) that's meant to be basically a "not null" test. Within a single AppDomain, this should be fine. It's kinda hard to tell without us being able to easily run the code ourselves...

Comment: I'd suggest changing the code to explicitly compare with `null`, partly to just check whether that helps (I wouldn't expect it to) and partly to make the question a lot clearer for people who don't use `MonoBehavior` a lot.

Comment: you are mixing static and instance variables and inheritance...im wondering what your goal is here...even if you get it to work...it might be hard to maintain this type of structure down the road

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your problem and cannot reproduce it, so there is something you are not showing us or telling us. Try writing a small, *complete* program that reproduces the problem and posting it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

It did not like new() for Objects for some reason. 
AddComponent() works though. Something 
to do with changing static classes to 
Individual instances.

```
Foo=gameObject.AddComponent<Bar>() as Bar;
```

Thank you all for your help. 
Cheers,
Clancy

Comment: AddComponent<Bar>() as Bar;